# Storing a reference to a java class in a database

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have some kind of job control with persistence via a database.

There is a interface for actions:

```
public interface IAction {
    Object perform(Work work, Map<String, String> parameter) throws Exception;
}
```

There are multiple implementations:

```
public class SingleFileConvertAction implements IAction {
    public InputStream perform(Work work, Map<String, String> parameter) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}

public class CacheDeleteAction implements IAction {
    public Object perform(Work work, Map<String, String> parameter) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
// ...
```

There is a job control class:

```
@Entity
public class ActionControl {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "work_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Work work;

    private IAction action;

    private Date requestTime;
    private Date startTime;
    private Date endTime;

    // ...

    private ActionControl() {}

    public ActionControl(Work work, String action, Map<String, String> parameter) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
        this.work = work;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to save the action control to the database. I only need to know, which action class to use. Everything else is saved in `work` and `parameter`.

I thought about saving a string and do a switch() to choose it like `"CacheDeleteAction" -> CacheDeleteAction` but I assume there is a better way to do it. Is it possible to save "CacheDeleteAction.class" in a database field? (I saw it in Spring annotations)

How to save a reference to a java class in a database?

Comment: There seems to be no `IAction` in your `ActionControl` class. Is that right?

Comment: Correct. I'm thinking about this problem. But I could add it, if it makes thinks better understandable. It's only to make the structure clear and make my problem understandable.

Comment: how about creating an enum for actions

Comment: OK but this would still end up in using a switch(), correct? I thought there might be an automatic mapping like it is done for some other data types.

Comment: That depends on your future usage of that field. I would assume a string might even be better than an enum, as you can use `Class.forName("classname with package")` to get the right class and probably even get an instance.

Answer (score 0):

as @XtremeBaumer said depends on your usage, if you need to create an instance later on then what XtremeBaumer has suggested would be preferred way, else with enum it would go something like this,

```
   public enum IActionEnum {
        CACHE_DELETE_ACTION("Cache delete action"),
        SINGLE_FILE_CONVERT_ACTION("Single file convert action"),

        private String actionDescription;

        IActionEnum(String description) {
            actionDescription= description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return actionDescription;
        }
    }
```

And whenever you would like to save it to DB you can use it like,

```
IAction actionControl = new IAction();
// set all other parameters
actionControl.setIAction(IActionEnum.CACHE_DELETE_ACTION)

actionControlRepository.save(actionControl);
```